# Can I reuse glass bottles with plastic lids for homemade sauces?

Tags: food-safety, sauce, food-preservation, botulism

I have bottles with plastic screw top lids (from supermarket bought hot sauce). Can I use these bottles for my homemade bbq/tomato sauce? I would sterilise the bottles as I usually do. I have previously reused bottles with metal lids and stored these on the shelf for months, successfully. I don’t plan to “can” the sauces in the bottles, I am using recipes that have enough vinegar to preserve without “canning”. The sauces are usually just poured hot into a sterilised jar and left on shelf.

Comment: Thanks J. I’m not “canning” in this instance, have updated my original post.

Comment: Just pouring a sauce into a sterilised jar and leaving it at room temperature is not safe using any type of jar, unless it's acidic enough to be "pickled".

Answer (score 1):

Reusing the bottles shouldn´t be a problem as long as they can be cleaned properly.
But I wouldn`t use them for canning for two reasons:

- Metal lids usually have a 'click' that ensures they keep the vacuum seal and allow you to check if it is still unbroken.
- Some sorts of plastic are not meant to be heated and when cooking the bottles for canning there is a risk that some chemicals (e.g. BPA) diffuse to the food.